Main app color: Red, should I change it?
I have an app and the main color used in it is red. Since it's a dating app I thought it would be fine. But red signifies danger in psychology, will that reduce the chance of getting matches for users? Should I change the colors used in the app?

Color perception is not a dogma.The color red is not only danger, it is also representative of love, among many other meanings.

There are graphic alternatives to "decrease" the incidence of the color red in only one of its perceptual meanings. For example:
Combine with other colors

Vary HSB

Minimize the main color visible percentage
The main color of an app does not imply that this color must be used constantly in 100% of the visible area.

Shape perception
Use shapes that affect the conceptual content:


These are just some possibilities about how to influence the conceptual content of a design, but the basis is knowing how to use contrast well depending on what you want to convey.

Danielillo nailed the explanation, definitely a good basis. It's important to remember that not any one thing only ever has a single meaning.
Yes, red refers to danger, but it also refers to love, passion and energy. Depending on the context, it could be a beautiful colour to add to a dating app.
Be sure to do some UI and UX research on some existing dating apps, like Tinder, Badoo and so forth, to get a feel for their colour usage.
Good luck!

Could have been a comment, as it only confirms the other answer.

@jazZRo My mistake, I'm new on the platform. Thanks for clarifying!

The red can be used take examples from

Reddit
Quora
Pinterest

Colour psychology is based on how you use it and your target audience. Alpha generation can more relate with bright RED like the Bright tone of Yellow is used by snapchat.
